Interpolation between arbitrary placed light probes
I am at the beginning of implementing light probes.
The light probes however are arbitrarily placed in 3D space, i.e. they are not placed in a uniform grid.
How would someone interpolate between different light probes in an efficient way?
In an uniform grid it's rather simple with linear interpolation, but how would I do that when I do not know the coordinates beforehand?


Have you looked into 3-dimensional Delaunay triangulation to divide your space into tetrahedra? Each tetrahedron would then define the portion of space in which to blend the four light probes at its vertices, and barycentric coordinates would give you the blend weights.
